# What is the Sandbox Endpoints to test paypal TLS 1.2 and HTTP/1.1 Upgrade

Tags: paypal, endpoint, payflowpro

We are using payflowpro to make credit card payments.

The current production URL is payflowpro.paypal.com
The current test URL is pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com

Paypal is doing TLS 1.2 and HTTP/1.1 Upgrade and provides a few endpoint sandboxs:

```
api.sandbox.paypal.com
api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com
api-aa.sandbox.paypal.com
api-aa-3t.sandbox.paypal.com
svcs.sandbox.paypal.com
pointofsale.sandbox.paypal.com
ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com
www.sandbox.paypal.com
```

Which one is applicable to payflowpro?

Thanks!

ct

Comment: The good news is that pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com is listed for TLS 1.2 and HTTP/1.1 as of February 15th 2017 and the main conversion isn't until June 30th.  I've not had any luck testing with the sandbox, so am considering just waiting until the pilot systems (which I know are reliable as we use them for testing now) move over as even then I've still got 4 months to update whatever little piece of code needs updated (our Payflow interface is pretty small and tightly contained).